# Haskell | Could not deduce from context

Tags: haskell

I have this code that does not compile. I'd like to understand why it can not deduce the types.

```
module Main where

data Combiner a = Combiner a (a -> Int)
comb = Combiner 3 (\x -> 5)

class HasValue a where
  getValue :: Int

instance HasValue Combiner where
  getValue (Combiner x f) = f x

main = print $ getValue comb
```

Here's the error:

```
main.hs:8:3: error:
• Could not deduce (HasValue a0)
  from the context: HasValue a
    bound by the type signature for:
               getValue :: HasValue a => Int
    at main.hs:8:3-17
  The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
• In the ambiguity check for ‘getValue’
  To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
  When checking the class method:
    getValue :: forall a. HasValue a => Int
  In the class declaration for ‘HasValue’
```

Comment: Shouldn't the signature of `getValue` be `a -> Int`?

Comment: it is probably not the only error. Sometimes it makes sense to start with the first one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given I understand it correctly, you defined the **wrong signature for `getValue`**. Now it is defined:

```
class HasValue a where
  getValue :: Int
```

So that means there can be different versions of `getValue`, but since these all return an `Int`, it is completely impossible to know which `instance` we want to pick.

Based on the `instance` declaration later in the file (and the name of the function) however, I think you were actually looking for:

```
class HasValue a where
  getValue :: a -> Int
```

Now Haskell can derive the `a` from the type of the *parameter* of the function application. Furthermore this also matches with your function body in the `instance HasValue`.

Furthermore the `Combiner` is *not* a *monotype*, so we need to add the type parameter in the head:

```
instance HasValue (Combiner a) where
  getValue (Combiner x f) = f x
```

Comment: There's another issue, though.  The `HasValue` instance should be `instance HasValue (Combiner a)`, not just `instance HasValue Combiner`.

Comment: Thank you. Also, are all types with * kinds are completely grounded?

Comment: @PetrasPurlys: after some rereading, I think that the term *monotype* is more appropriate, and yes, those are types with kind `*`.